# Babel async await

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I've spent last few hours trying to make it work but it just doesn't for no apparent reason. I have all the required packages and settings. I get no errors, `async` and `await` just doesn't wait.

I use Webpack to require the polyfill files that Babel adds, *e.g* `babel-runtime/regenerator`.

### Code:

```
async function getData() {
    let data = await ajaxCall();
    console.log(data);
}

function ajaxCall() {
    let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=london';

    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
                return JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
            } 
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

getData();

// It logs "undefined" and then ajax response AFTER
```

---

### .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
    "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

**Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?**

Comment: `await`  expects function that return promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `async` and `await` to work you need to return something from your `await`ed call that the JS runtime can use to know when to continue the function that is `await`ing the result.  The "type" that is required for `async` / `await` interop is called [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Your `ajaxCall` returns `undefined`, which doesn't tell the JS runtime anything, so it doesn't `await` because there is nothing to wait for.  If you want to make this work, simply return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from `ajaxCall` and resolve it when your ajax request is fulfilled.

At the simplest:

```
function ajaxCall() {
  let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=london';
  // The new `window.fetch` API returns a promise for you
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}
```

or using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
function ajaxCall() {
    let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=london';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // resolve instead of return inside of a Promise closure
            resolve(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
          } else {
            // reject instead of throw
            // (will throw the error at the `await` expression.)
            reject(Error(`Received status code ${xmlhttp.status}`));
          }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a promise from the ajaxCall().
Code should look something like that:

```
function ajaxCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=london';

    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
          resolve(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
        }
      }
    // handle error: reject(error);
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  })
}
```

then:

```
async function getData() {
    try {
        let data = await ajaxCall();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {
        // do something with error
    }
}
```

Note that I used es6 arrow functions